# Not able to access the member field from parent class in JAXB XML response

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb

I am trying to use JAXB and give the response in XML but I cannot access the members from Parent class. I am getting the following response without the lastname field which is in the parent class.

```
<A>
  <Child>
    <firstname>ABC</firstName>
  </Child>
</A>
```

I have a class in this sample format:

```
@xmlrootelement
class A{
    @xmlelement(required = true)
    List<Child> childList;
}

class Parent{
     @xmlelement(required = true)
     protected string lastName;
 }

@XmlRootelement
class Child extends Parent{
     @xmlelement(required = true)
     String firstName;
}
```

Comment: Could also post the code where you are trying to parse the xml.

Comment: He is not parsing XML, he is generating XML

Comment: i am using POSTMAN (rest client) to call my rest web service and there i am getting a response where I have a problem.